# OpenCV4 locateROI / Offset in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-recognition, roi

I'm trying to select the roi offset in a image in opencv 4.2, but i don't get it working. (I'm doing a recognition in the roi and want to mark it with a line in the original image.)

I thought that I could use on "roi" in the following code the locateROI() function but I get always the -> *"AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'locateROI'"*.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.JPG',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
roi = img[10:200, 10:200]
roi.locateROI()
```

As help I used [get Original image from ROI image in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498373/get-original-image-from-roi-image-in-opencv)

Anybody who ca help me?

Comment: Python OpenCV bindings don't use `cv::Mat`, instead they use numpy arrays. Hence, calling C++ member functions of the `Mat` class on those Python arrays is futile. I can't find a straightforward way to do the same in numpy -- the closes I've found so far is doing something like `np.byte_bounds(roi)[0] - np.byte_bounds(roi.base)[0]` to get a byte offset of the first element of the view relative to the first element of the parent array. You still have to do some simple math to handle multiple dimensions.

Comment: However, in the example above, you already know the position of the ROI, since you explicitly stated it when creating it. Easiest would be just to store those parameters into a variable and use them when necessary.

Comment: Okay, thanks!  I will try it this way. I have already  expected that the locateROI etc. methods are not available because I haven't found them in any docs from numpy.